# Circular Cell Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question regarding a circular cell reference. I have come up with an example that illustrates my dilemma and I attached an illustration.

Here's the deal. My house needs ***heat*** and it needs ***electricity***:

**My house needs 7 units of heat and 1 unit of electricity.**

My generator is 50% efficient. So for every unit of electricity used to power the generator, I only get .5 units of electricity for my house. You can neither create nor destroy energy, so the other 50% that isn't turned into electricity, turns into heat.

My heat pump consumes 1 unit of electricity in order to produce 2 units of heat. This means that the heat pump is 200% efficient. Additionally we get to use the waste heat from the generator.

Please look at the attached example. I drew out the scenario so you can visualize it. Subscript E is used to denote electricity. Subscript H is used to denote heat.

I need to be able to change the generator efficiency, heat pump efficiency, and how much electricity the house needs.​ I would like to be able to manipulate each variable.

Can anyone help me input this into excel???

Thanks!!!

-Jon

[Example of Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4psfi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Although I doubt the physical correctness of your approach, the math problem is solvable in Excel with goal seek.

Let's have the following sheet:

[image]

Formulas:

`C4`: `=-(C2*B4)`

`D4`: `=-(C2+C4)`

`C6`: `=-(C4+C8)`

`D6`: `=-(C6*B6)`

`D8`: `=-(D4+D6)`

`D10`: `=D8/C8`

Consumption are negative values, production are positive values.

Now change the variables, for example `B4`, `B6` or `C8` and call What-If Analysis, Goal Seek. `D10` must be 7 and `C2` is the changing cell.

---

A real math solution would be:

Generator Input = `gi`

Generator Efficiency = `geff`

Heat Pump Efficiency = `hpeff`

House Electricity Needed = `hen`

House Heat Needed = `hhn`

```
(gi*geff - hen) * hpeff + gi*(100%-geff) = hhn

gi*geff*hpeff - hen*hpeff + gi*(100%-geff) = hhn
gi*geff*hpeff + gi*(100%-geff) = hhn + hen*hpeff 
gi * (geff*hpeff + (100%-geff)) = hhn + hen*hpeff 

gi = (hhn + hen*hpeff ) / (geff*hpeff + (100%-geff))
```

6kW = (7kW + 1kW*200%) / (50%*200% + (100% - 50%))

6kW = 9kW / 1,5

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange this a little to make it more simple.

You're trying to solve for a + b:

a = Heat Pump Input

b = Generator Input

With the following input values:

c = Generator Efficiency

d = Heat Pump Efficiency

H = Heat Needed

W = Electricity Needed

Now, we know:

W = bc

H = ad + b(1-c)

Hence we can derive:

b = W/e

a = (H-W(1-c)/c)/d

Input your values for c,d,H and W and you get your result.

Comment: When you derive a = (h-w(1-e)/e)/d , what is "e"?

Comment: @JonBass My bad; that was supposed to be a c. I admit that the notation and explanation here isn't brilliant. I had it all nicely written out in pencil, and then realised that it wouldn't translate to Stack Overflow so nicely.